# JDK 1.4.2 - where can I download the source?

Tags: java, source, oracle

I want to install Java JRE 1.4.2 or JDK 1.4.2 on a recent Amazon Linux server. The best option so far seems to install from source. However - where can I download this? I believe 1.4 is still from the Sun era, but I can't find it on the [**Oracle**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase14-419411.html) site, and the sun site is gone. [**Openjdk**](http://openjdk.java.net/install/index.html) has no 1.4 download afaik.

**Where can I download Java 1.4.2 source code?**

As the goal is to get the installation working, other options are welcome. I tried to install the bin file, but got an error: cannot execute binary file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution works on a 64 bit machine. Download j2sdk-1_4_2_19-linux-i586.bin from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase14-419411.html). Run it:

```
sudo sh j2sdk-1_4_2_19-linux-i586.bin
```

You can move this folder to `/opt/` or where you want it. After installing, you can check if it works:

```
/opt/jre-1.4.2/bin/java -version
```

Then you may get the following error message:

```
-bash: /opt/jre-1.4.2/bin/java: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Installing `glibc.i686` will fix this:

```
sudo yum -y install glibc.i686
```

Another try:

```
/opt/jre-1.4.2/bin/java -version
```

Output:

```
java version "1.4.2_19"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.4.2_19-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.4.2_19-b04, mixed mode)
```

NB: this answer doesn't provide the source code, but gives a solution to installing Java 1.4.2, which was the underlying request.

Answer (score 2):

You can't download the complete source code for Java 1.4.2, Sun never published it (as far as I'm aware). On the Oracle page you link to, scroll down to [version 1.4.2_19](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase14-419411.html#j2sdk-1.4.2_19-oth-JPR) and you'll find installation packages for 32-bit Intel CPUs, which you may be able to use on your Amazon server (if you can install the necessary 32-bit supporting libraries).